# Trying to get local notification to work in iphone app

Tags: iphone, notifications

I am trying to create a local notification on my iphone app.
I want it to be launched once per day at 9am.

But nothing is happening, either in the simulator or on the ipod.

Here is the full code from xcode in my appdelegate.m file.
This app was created in dreamweaver using phonegap...is that an issue?
do i even have the code in the right place?

```
    //
//  assignmentAppDelegate.m
//  assignment
//
//  Created by Noel Chenier on 23 December, 2011.
//  Copyright  2011. All rights reserved.
//

#import "assignmentAppDelegate.h"
#import "PhoneGapViewController.h"

@implementation assignmentAppDelegate


- (id) init
{   
    /** If you need to do any extra app-specific initialization, you can do it here
     *  -jm
     **/
    return [super init];
}

/**
 * This is main kick off after the app inits, the views and Settings are setup here.
 */
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{   
    [ super applicationDidFinishLaunching:application ];
}

-(id) getCommandInstance:(NSString*)className
{
    /** You can catch your own commands here, if you wanted to extend the gap: protocol, or add your
     *  own app specific protocol to it. -jm
     **/
    return [super getCommandInstance:className];
}

/**
 Called when the webview finishes loading.  This stops the activity view and closes the imageview
 */
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView 
{
    return [ super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView ];
}

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView 
{
    return [ super webViewDidStartLoad:theWebView ];
}

/**
 * Fail Loading With Error
 * Error - If the webpage failed to load display an error with the reson.
 */
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error 
{
    return [ super webView:theWebView didFailLoadWithError:error ];
}

/**
 * Start Loading Request
 * This is where most of the magic happens... We take the request(s) and process the response.
 * From here we can re direct links and other protocalls to different internal methods.
 */
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    return [ super webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType ];
}


- (BOOL) execute:(InvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    return [ super execute:command];
}


- (void)scheduleNotification{

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:(NSYearCalendarUnit |    NSMonthCalendarUnit   |NSMinuteCalendarUnit ) fromDate:today];
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:dateComponents.day];
    [dateComps setMonth:dateComponents.month];
    [dateComps setYear:dateComponents.year];
    [dateComps setHour:9];
    [dateComps setMinute:00];
    NSDate *fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = fireDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotif.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;

    localNotif.alertBody = @"Don't forget your 365 Day Photo Challenge Assignment";
    localNotif.alertAction = @"LAUNCH";



    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];
}


- (void)dealloc
{
    [ super dealloc ];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it.  I placed the code after:

```
/**
 * This is main kick off after the app inits, the views and Settings are setup here.
 */
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
```